# Are internships the only way to secure a job after graduation..?

Tags: resume, job-search, hiring-process, united-states

I'm a recent graduate with an Information Systems degree who didn't do internships during school. Its been two months with no luck. Are most companies looking for candidates with internships when hiring for entry level jobs?

Comment: No, it's not "the only way", but it sure does help. Just keep at it, and if you're not having a lot of luck you might ask someone to give you feedback on your resume or otherwise help you practice for interviews.

Comment: What did you do instead of internships? Depending on what it was, it may be worthwhile to include on your resume.

Comment: Can you add a country tag please?

Comment: Do something noteworthy on your own and someone will hire you.

Comment: Portfolios of work can go a long way if you're in an industry that lends itself to creating a work portfolio.  In software, make a public Github repo with some of your work.

Comment: Well, I did two years at a community college and than transferred into a university. I usually go back home (Egypt) every summer to visit my family and seeing how most internships are during the summer, it was not possible. I've submitted around 30 applications so far with no reply. I might need feedback on my resume as well. Tough part is not giving up...

Comment: @Killer066, it took a couple of hundred applications to land my first post-college job but I graduated in a year when there was an economic downturn.  Don't give up hope, try harder and while you work on getting hired, work on something open source you can use to show something besides the degree.

Comment: If I can offer some advice on the resume, try going to a English TA to read over your resume rather than the career center. I went to a career center at my university and got no real help on my resume until I went to this English TA who helped me out greatly.

Comment: Right now I'm basically just applying for IT jobs with specialization in business analyst, system analyst, data analyst. Since my degree is in Information systems I obviously can't work in finance, marketing, accounting etc..Its just hard not getting ANY responses. It would be nice if they at least told me I wasn't selected...

Comment: I got an Information Systems degree as well, and DID do internships.  It still took me over two months to find a job.  Definitely tough to not give up, but keep plugging away!

Comment: I really think the reason I'm not getting responses is because of my resume. Getting feedback from you guys would help me out a lot. Should I post another question or a resume feedback?

Comment: Make friends at the places you want to get hired. Life is about who you know when you need a job.

Comment: **Vote to leave open.** These close votes don't make sense. OP isn't asking for job searching advice, he's asking a simple question that has a simple answer. If answers are giving job advice instead of answering the question, downvote or comment on those, don't punish the question.

Answer (score 3):

They do tend to go for more experienced employees, just make sure you go for a Junior position. You could also start at a smaller company since they tend to have less requirements and might just hire someone who is cheap preferably (these companies are always out there, but you don't want to work there permanently).

I for one had my job before I graduated I might have been lucky to have been granted a position by contacts, there is no single right way to build your career.

So either, do an internship as volunteer, or start at a smaller less profitable company etc. What you could also consider is making sure you have a decent portfolio, when you; for example are a developer, you could fill your Github account with some projects from study or hobby projects. Make sure they're up to standard and skill so potential employers can analyse and rate your skills based on the work you've done.

Comment: I did do many projects in university. The  biggest one was we made a visual studios database program for our university where users log-in into a database where they  can access room info, booking rooms, request service etc.. It was a project we worked on through out the semester. Should I include this on my resume?

Comment: If you think it is relevant, why not. If not on your resume you can always embed a portfolio besides the resume. Many people actually put projects on their resumes when experience is slim.

Comment: You could also, make a project as a hobby thing to show off as well, it also shows that you work on keeping yourself challenged and learning. (Having heart for the business etc.

Answer (score 1):

As someone that did a Computer Science degree but had no work experience in the IT field when I graduated, it took me about 4 months to get my first job out of university and this was back in 1997 when the dot-com boom was going. You are likely competing against other graduates that do have work experience and thus you may have to get more creative about where you are finding jobs to apply so that you aren't competing with such a big pool of applicants. This could involve networking, seeing if friends or family have connections, etc. as a solution as I ended up being the only applicant after an initial screen for my situation which may have been rare to imagine back then.

Answer (score 0):

Having been in your shoes two years ago - you just need to be the right candidate for the role. I didn't have any experience, but I did have some projects I've worked, some apps I've made, in University I did do alot of stuff related to what I was applying for and I just wrote my CV and letter around the role.

Comment: I did do many projects in university. The  biggest one was we made a visual studios database program for our university where users log-in into a database where they  can access room info, booking rooms, request service etc.. It was a project we worked on through out the semester. Should I include this on my resume?

Comment: I would, and I did. I included my Final year Project (my dissertation) and various small projects I did. Pretty much everything I had, to show that I was employee material and not just another lemming.

Comment: Where would I put this under? I have 4 sections. Education, experience, core qualifications and professional summary.

Comment: Either 2 or 4, most likely "Experience" under sub-section "Projects I've worked on" or however you feel like wording it.

Answer (score 0):

Being able to demonstrate your value in your respective field is how you secure a job.

Having an internship is helpful,  but if your skills are in demand and you can demonstrate your value, finding employment should not be an issue

Summary: aspire to be the best at what you do